# how pass a function's variable inside a calling function using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Using the following code I'm unable to get value of this.select inside the calling function change... see below

```
function getSelection(selectionType) {
    this.select = selectionType;
    alert(this.select); // works
    this.getFile = function() {
        $(".file").change(function() {
            alert($(this).attr("id")); // works
            alert(this.select); // says undefined
            if ($(this).attr("id") == this.select) {
                alert("test"); // no display
            }
        });
    };
}​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cache `this`:

```
function getSelection(selectionType) {
    var that = this; // <========================
    this.select = selectionType;
    alert(this.select);

    this.getFile = function() {
        $(".file").change(function() {
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
            alert(that.select);
            if ($(this).attr("id") == that.select) {
                alert("test");
            }
        });
    }
}​
```

Comment: wow, your solution worked but don't understand why. thanks gdoron.. can't accept the answer, I have to wait 5 more minutes